# Difference between SSD and Mobilenet

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, object-detection

I am confusing between SSD and mobilenet. As far as I know, both of them are neural network. SSD provides localization while mobilenet provides classification. Thus the combination of SSD and mobilenet can produce the object detection. The image is taken from [SSD paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02325). The default classification network of SSD is VGG-16. So, for SSD Mobilenet, VGG-16 is replaced with mobilenet. Are my statements correct?

Where can I get more information about SSD Mobilenet especially that one available on Tensorflow model zoo?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**SSD** - single shot detector - is a NN architecture designed for detection purposes - which means localization(bounding boxes) and classification at once.

**Mobilenet**- (https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04861) - efficient architecture introduced by Google (using depthwise and pointwise convolutions). It can be used for classification purposes, or as a feature extractor for other (i.e. detection).

In the SSD paper they present the use of VGG NN as the **feature extractor** for the detection, the features maps are being taken from several different layers (resolutions) and being fed to their corresponding classification and localization  layers (Classification head and Regression head).

So actually, one can decide to use a different kind of feature extractor - like MobileNet-SSD - which means you use SSD arch. while your feature extractor is mobilenet arch.

By reading the SSD paper, and the mobilenet paper you would be able to understand the model exist in the model zoo.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of deep neural networks, Base network, and detection network. MobileNet, VGG-Net, LeNet are base networks.

The base network provides high-level features for classification or detection. If you use an entirely connected layer at the end of these networks, you have a classification. But you can remove a fully connected layer and replace it with detection networks, like SSD, Faster R-CNN, and so on. In general, SSD use of last convolutional layer on base networks for the detection task. MobileNet just like other base networks uses of convolution to produce high-level features.